# I'm passing dispatcher from View to the ViewModel using DI. How to unit test this

Tags: unit-testing, mvvm, dispatcher

In my WPF MVVM multithreaded application , i 'm passing dispatcher from view to viewmodel,

```
public ViewModel(Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
_dispatcher = dispatcher;
}
```

so that ViewModel is free to call Invoke on the _dispatcher at will.My Unit tests would have to inject a Dispatcher into this. How to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Make an interface IDispatcher and pass that to your ViewModel. This way you can easily test it and has the added benefit that your VM can be more cross platform since you can now plugin a WinStore and WinPhone implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To Unit Test on UI you need to create environment in Unit Test to call any method in your View Model. 
In your case i think you need to user some framework to create environment such as [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/)